# Consistent gradually faded text effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Building a blog site, where the blog text will be gradually faded as in the following image:

[image: example of gradually faded text]

In the above image, the multi-line title doesn't effect the fading effect,i.e the text starts fading at the same place on each article.

In the case of the example below, when headings span multiple lines, the fading effect area changes.

How can I keep the fading effect consistent regardless of the length of the header?

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
div.absolute {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1))
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <h1>This is a single line</h1>
  <p id="landing-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend consequat mi eget pretium. Integer ac nunc massa. Proin dapibus et nunc vel luctus. Nulla quis justo et nisi mollis congue. Etiam consectetur nunc a felis aliquet finibus id ut arcu. Fusce faucibus eros ut ante faucibus aliquet. Quisque maximus arcu in quam bibendum, vitae luctus justo dapibus. Praesent ac rutrum quam. Nam sagittis sem et leo efficitur, ac lacinia magna luctus.</p>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
  <h1>This is<br>multiple lines</h1>
  <p id="landing-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eleifend consequat mi eget pretium. Integer ac nunc massa. Proin dapibus et nunc vel luctus. Nulla quis justo et nisi mollis congue. Etiam consectetur nunc a felis aliquet finibus id ut arcu. Fusce faucibus eros ut ante faucibus aliquet. Quisque maximus arcu in quam bibendum, vitae luctus justo dapibus. Praesent ac rutrum quam. Nam sagittis sem et leo efficitur, ac lacinia magna luctus.</p>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Edit : I set fixed height for the caption and text container classes :

```
caption {
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.relative {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

It helped, but there's another problem :

[[Here's how it looks now][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebp5K.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebp5K.png)
There are whitespaces between the caption and date(since I set fixed height for caption class). How can I deal with whitespace while keeping the fading effect intact?

Comment: Set a fixed `height` and `oveflow:hidden` on text body containers (`.relative` in your case).

Comment: The website of that screenshot is [Polygon.com](http://www.polygon.com/), a video game news and review blogging site. Just so yo know, that text does not scroll. The source of the site has it set to `overflow:hidden`. I added an answer below that offers scrolling.

Comment: @Ouroborus Your suggestion did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

The container for both the text and title should get a fixed height and the overflow of the rest of the block should be hidden, like:

```
.container{
     height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

This forces the relative and absolute div to end at the end of the container div.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.landing-content {
  height: 45px; --> fixed height
  overflow: hidden;  --> do not overflow height with additional content
}
```

HTML: (+class name for `p`):

```
<div class="relative">
        <p id="landing-content" class="landing-content"><%- blog.body.substring(0,400); %></p>
        <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the gradient to the bottom.

```css
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

I generated the CSS Gradient here: http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

```css
background: linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%,  /* #E7E7E200 */
  rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, /* #E7E7E2FF */
  rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100% /* #E7E7E2FF */
);
```

```css
.article {
  position: relative;
  background: #E7E7E2;
}
.content {
  /* Enable to lock scrolling.
   *
   * overflow: hidden;
   * height: 95vh;
  */
}
.article .fade-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75vh;
  background: rgba(231, 231, 226, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0)), color-stop(90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(231, 231, 226, 0) 0%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 90%, rgba(231, 231, 226, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e7e7e2', endColorstr='#e7e7e2', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bgrins/loremjs/master/lorem.js"></script>
<div class="article">
  <div id="paragraphs" class="content" data-lorem="10"></div>
  <div class="fade-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't needed vendor prefixes on `linear-gradient` for a long time now. (Still need `filter` for IE9) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: @Ouroborus It's still ok to have them for legacy browsers. It does not hurt anything. Also, I generated the gradient.